# Getting error while install package in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install some packages like discord.js, but it gives me this error. How can I fix it?

```
WARN engine discord.js@13.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=16.6.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine discord.js@13.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=16.6.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.loadDep:ws → resolveWithN ▌ ╢████░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine discord-api-types@0.26.1: wanted: {"node":">=12"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine form-data@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine ws@8.5.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @sapphire/async-queue@1.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=v14.0.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: loadDep:ws → 304          ▐ ╢████░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @discordjs/collection@0.4.0: wanted: {"node":">=16.0.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {loadDep:ws → network      ▌ ╢████░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @discordjs/builders@0.11.0: wanted: {"node":">=16.0.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {"loadDep:zod → request     ▌ ╢████░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @sindresorhus/is@4.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5loadDep:form-data → resol ▐ ╢████░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine form-data@3.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=/home/ssthunder
├─┬ discord.js@13.6.0
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bufferutil@^4.0.1
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY encoding@^0.1.0
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY utf-8-validate@^5.0.2
└─┬ peer@0.6.1
  ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bufferutil@^4.0.1
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY utf-8-validate@^5.0.2

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ssthunder/package.json'
npm WARN node-fetch@2.6.7 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@8.5.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@8.5.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ssthunder No description
npm WARN ssthunder No repository field.
npm WARN ssthunder No README data
npm WARN ssthunder No license field.
```

Comment: I'd say update Node.js, but there's really no question to answer here, it's just a message log.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In your error, it says that *Discord.js* requires *Node.js* at `v16.6.0`, and *npm* at `v7.0.0` (as it says below, extracted from your error).

```
WARN engine discord.js@13.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=16.6.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
```

The current versions you have are extremely low, so I recommend updating *Node.js* every month.

**To update *Node.js*, download the installer from the official website ([nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/)).** When you run the installer, it will automatically delete the old version.

Once you've updated *Node.js* and *npm* to their required versions (or higher), then you can run the install command, and it should install then.

Answer (score 0):

Your node & npm versions are older. Update them and make sure your local account name doesn't have non-ASCII characters.